# Linq case statement on boolean field depending on int value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a **Category** table where I want to query like bellow with linq

```
 declare @Isactive int
set @Isactive=0
select * from Category
where isdeleted=0 and isactive=
 case @Isactive
    when 0 then 'false'
    when 1 then 'true'
    when 2 then isactive
    else Isactive end
```

for that I write bellow linq query but not working

```
public List<Category> Search(Int16 IsActive, string Category)
{
    from rarc in db.Category.AsEnumerable()
                        where rarc.IsDeleted == false &&
                        && IsActive == 2 ? rarc.IsActive == rarc.IsActive : IsActive == 1 ? rarc.IsActive == true : rarc.IsActive == false


}
```

above query fetch all data without checking IsActive field.

Comment: I don't believe your code even compiles.

Comment: Are you using EF or DataTable? AsEnumerable is not performant with the former.

Comment: Note that `rarc.IsActive == rarc.IsActive` is always `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `&&` operator takes [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) over `?:`. Use explicit brackets to control operator precedence.

```
from rarc in db.Category.AsEnumerable()
    where rarc.IsDeleted == false &&
        (IsActive == 2 ? rarc.IsActive == rarc.IsActive : 
         IsActive == 1 ? rarc.IsActive == true : 
                         rarc.IsActive == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = (from rarc in db.Category
    where rarc.IsDeleted == false &&
        (IsActive == 2 ? 
             rarc.IsActive == rarc.IsActive : 
         IsActive == 1 ? 
             rarc.IsActive == true : 

             rarc.IsActive == false)).tolist()
```

using brackets before when cases